# Assign Torch and Tensorflow models two separate GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, pytorch, torch

I am comparing two pre-trained models, one is in Tensorflow and one is in Pytorch, on a machine that has multiple GPUs. Each model fits on one GPU. They are both loaded in the same Python script. How can I assign one GPU to the Tensorflow model and another GPU to the Pytorch model?

Setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1` only tells both models that these GPUs are available - how can I (within Python I guess), make sure that Tensorflow takes GPU 0 and Pytorch takes GPU 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to `torch.device`. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html?highlight=device#torch.torch.device

In particular do

```
device=torch.device("gpu:0")
tensor = tensor.to(device)
```

or to load a pretrained model

```
device=torch.device("gpu:0")
model = model.to(device)
```

to put tensor/model on gpu 0.

Similarly tensorflow has tf.device. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device. Its usage is described here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu

for tensorflow to load model on gpu:0 do,

```
with tf.device("gpu:0"):
     load_model_function(model_path)
```

Comment: okay but for this I would have to go change the pretrained model - any way I can do this for tensorflow and torch in general (e.g. while loading the libraries)?

Comment: You won't have to change the pre-trained model, I am updating my answer to reflect that.